# How to cast double to T generic type in Java?

Tags: java, casting

I'm implementing a Range class that represents a numeric or date range that has a lower bound and an upper bound that can be of any data type. For numeric ranges I want it to be able to automatically define ranges with bounds to either positive or negative Infinity whenever the client doesn't pass in a lower bound or upper bound parameter. I have layout some code that looks like this:

```
public final class Range<T extends Comparable> implements Serializable {
    // FIELDS:
    private final T lowerBound;
    private final T upperBound;

    // CONSTRUCTORS:
    public Range(T lowerBound, T upperBound) {
        Double positiveInfinityAsDouble = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Double negativeInfinityAsDouble = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        if (lowerBound instanceof Double && upperBound instanceof Double) {
            this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
            this.upperBound = upperBound;
        } else if (lowerBound == null) {
            this.lowerBound = positiveInfinityAsDouble;
            this.upperBound = upperBound;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid bounds.");
        }
    }

    // GETTERS & SETTERS:
    ...
    
    // METHODS:
    ...
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and it is highlighting an error in the `else if` block on line `this.lowerBound = positiveInfinityAsDouble;` saying: `Required type: T, Provided: Double`.

Is there any way to cast generic T type to double or any object in Java?

Comment: You are missunderstanding the problem. The thing is, an user can pick whatever he likes for `T` (as long as it is `Comparable`). So he might for example choose `Dog`. A `Dog` is **not** a `Double`. So treating it as double makes no sense. Your method, as it is written, **must** be capable of dealing with **all classes** `T` that are `Comparable`. Not just `Double`s.

Comment: Why use `T` at all when your bounds should always be of type `Double`? Or why require `Double` for other types? I'd use something else for the "inifinite" bounds, e.g. `null` so you could use any type that fits your `T`.

Comment: It sounds to me that you are using generics incorrectly and on top, requiring the wrong interface. `Comparable` gives you `compareTo` but it seems you want more, namely the possibility to compute a **distance** between both. That is much more than just being able to compare two items. You need a **Metric**.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the compiler happy by casting to T:

```
        } else if (lowerBound == null) {
            this.lowerBound = (T) positiveInfinityAsDouble;
            this.upperBound = upperBound;
```

But be aware that this might not be the best idea as you can't be sure T is representing a Double.

EDIT:

To explain how this might blow up at runtime, consider this example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Range<Integer> range = new Range<>(null, 5);
        System.out.println("range = " + range);
        Integer low = range.getLowerBound();
        System.out.println("low = " + low);
    }
```

This leads to the following exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

> Required type: T, Provided: Double.

> > Is there any way to cast generic T type to double or any object in Java?

You get it backwards. You **have** a **Double** object, and you want it to assign to something that needs to be your **generic** type **T**. That is what the message tells you.

When you instantiate a Range object, then the **compiler** figures the specific type of T. Assume that T would be Long. How could you possible treat a Double as Long?

In other words: your real problem is that you are misusing the type system because you don't fully understand generics.

And just adding a **cast** to T just defers the error. In case your T ends up to be Long for example, you risk class cast exceptions.

You only cast when "you" know better than the compiler. In this case, you clearly don't.

Answer (score 0):

> Range class that represents a numeric or *date range* that has a lower bound and an upper bound that can be of *any data type*.

You've already stated that the type of the range could be anything that matches `T extends Comparable<T>` (note that `Comparable` is also generic).

There isn't a common definition of infinity for "any" type, e.g. dates and numbers would be defined differently.

So you need to use something that can represent missing bounds and handle that specifically. You could use special values, `null` or `Optional<T>`.

Your methods would then need to handle that. Example using `null`:

```
public void inRange(T value) {
  //lower bound must be present and value is smaller
  if( lowerBound != null && lowerBound.compareTo(value) > 0) {
    return false;
  }

  //upper bound must be present and value is greater
  if( upperBound != null && upperBound.compareTo(value) < 0) {
    return false;
  }

  //value is not smaller than lower bound and not greater than upper bound
  //so it is in range
  return true;
}
```